# Tex sending in another command

Tags: linux, bash, shell

suppose I have a text file something.txt. written with
4062,2016-12-31

I want to send "4062" in one command and "2016-12-31" as a string in another command in a script. Can it be done with BASH scripting?

Comment: Sure can. The problem is that there are many ways to do something like that, but the exact details very much depend on the exact content of that file, and what exactly you want to do with it. In that sense,you could look into tools such as sed, awk, and so on; or simply generic tutorials about shell programming; but don't expect that sit down with you to digest your problem in full depth to teach you how to solve it. We help with specific questions; not with "me vision, but no clue, please fill the gap".

Comment: What, precisely, do you mean by "send in a command"?

Comment: like my command is '{print $2",0"$1",field1,field2"}'. I want to send 4062 in field1 and 2016-12-31 in field2. This command is kept in another file.

Answer (score 1):

```
IFS="," read -r a b < file

echo "$a"
echo "$b"
```

Output:

```
4062
2016-12-31
```

Answer (score 0):

This would work in most cases, unless you are handling a very large file.

```
for line $(cat yourfile.txt)
do
  field1=$(echo $line | cut -f1 -d,)
  field2=$(echo $line | cut -f2 -d,)
  your_command_1 $field1
  your_command_2 $field2
done
```

Comment: `while read line ; do ... ; done <  yourfile.txt` won't suffer from large files.

Comment: like my command is '{print $2",0"$1",field1,field2"}'. I want to send 4062 in field1 and 2016-12-31 in field2. This command is kept in another file

Answer (score 0):

```
a=$(cat file.txt); IFS=',' list=($a) ; echo ${list[0]}; echo ${list[1]}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. **Flaggers / reviewers:** [For code-only answers such as this one, downvote, don't delete!](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260413/2747593) (Note: This answer may actually be simple enough to make an explanation, and thus downvotes, unnecessary. You may still want to add an explanation to prevent more NAA/VLQ flags.)

Comment: Hey, what about educational effect of thinking about 'how this one-liner works'? Seriously, it is simple bunch of code.